# video driver amd stopped responding and has recovered

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, crash, amd-radeon

so as the title says I get this error. I tried everything I could find online, but it didn't help.
I hope some of you might know the cause of this, because it usually happens:

1) When I run **some** games.

2) When I 'send' packets(information), let's take LoL(League of Legends) as an example, if I just minimize the game, nothing crashes, however if I try to play(move, attack, etc) it crashes then.

3) Another thing is that I tried running Dota with high graphics and it crashed, but with low it works.

What I tried to do:

1) Update drivers

2) Increased TdrDelay

3) Ran sfc/scannow

4) Checked if the system isn't overclocking

5) Unistalled Chrome(it helped some)

It might be that the card doesn't get enough power? But it should, unless the source is broken.

PC Specs:
1) AMD Radeon HD 7700

2) i5-4440 - 3.1Ghz

3) Motherboard: H87-HD3

4) Driver version is: 23.20.782.259

5) The power supply has a power of 550W

6) Windows 7.

Thank you.

Comment: Describe in detail "everything I could find online" that you tried.  Specify brand and model of computer, CPU model and speed, version of Windows.  Specify version of video driver software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" after computer is idle](https://superuser.com/questions/415872/display-driver-stopped-responding-and-has-recovered-after-computer-is-idle)

Comment: Updated the post, the PC doesn't have a model, as it was custom made(not by me).

Comment: Nope, that is a bit different, my PC doesn't crash when idle, also that solutions didn't help, but thanks anyways!